# Has Chrome improperly implemented the dataTransfer object?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dto

When I do this in dragstart event:

```
e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'text');
e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', 'html');
e.dataTransfer.setData('application/x-bookmark', 'bookmark');
```

and this in drop event:

```
for (var i = 0; i < e.dataTransfer.types.length; i++) {
   var type = e.dataTransfer.types[i];
   console.log(type + ":" + e.dataTransfer.getData(type));
}
```

I was supposed to have:

```
text/plain:text
text/html:html
application/x-bookmark:bookmark
```

as what I got in FF, but actually I got:

```
Text:text
text/plain:text
```

in Chrome. Where are those data gone? Does this mean chrome did not implement the dataTransfer object properly? And what can I do about this?

I ran this in Chrome 4.0.266.0

Comment: Isn't Chrome 4 still beta? Did you try it on 3?

Comment: Is that mimetype registered in the browser?

Comment: what is the result if you try Safari(webkit)?

Comment: I don't know about Safari, but [Arora](http://arora.googlecode.com/) version 0.10.2 (WebKit version 533.3) does not have this bug. See also my related answer in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767128/what-format-mime-type-should-i-use-for-html5-drag-and-drop-operations/6794282#6794282

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is a bug in Chrome. See issues [31037](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=31037) and issue [30240](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30240) in the chromium issue tracker (chromium is the open source version of google chrome). I see no other solution than waiting for the bug to be fixed. You can help them fixing it by providing a simple test case.

Comment: Still an open issue as of Chrome 12.

Comment: Still an open issue as of Chrome 13

Comment: Still an open issue as of Chrome 18

Comment: Again/still an issue as of Chrome 24

Comment: Again/still an issue as of Version 79.0.3945.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)