# What format (MIME Type) should I use for HTML5 drag and drop operations?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, dto

I'm starting to experiment with HTML5 Drag and Drop. Then, in the dragstart event handler we should run `setData()`, which receives two parameters: *format* and *data*.

```
function dragstart_handler(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'foobar');
}
```

I want to drag some kind of "object" from one container into another container, inside my web application. By "object", I mean something that has multiple attributes (color, text, author, date, …).

What kind of *format* (or MIME Type) should I use?

- `text/plain`?
- `text/x-myapp-myobjtype`?
- `application/x-myapp-myobjtype`?
- `application/x-myapp.myobjtype+json`?
- something else?
- more than one?

How should I encode my object (the *data* parameter of `setData()`)?

- Comma-separated (or any other delimiter) key=value pairs?
- Serialize the object using JSON?
- Just an id, and at the dropzone I must retrieve the full object using just the id?
- Send just a reference to the object, without even serializing anything? (not possible, the *data* argument must be a string)

(I realize that "How to enconde an object for Drag and Drop" could be another question here, but it is closely related to the choice of MIME Type)

---

Some references:

- http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/dnd.html
- http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/dnd.html#dnd
- https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DragDrop/Drag_Operations
- https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DragDrop/DataTransfer
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

Comment: It really depends on exactly what you're doing, but 'application/json' and a JSON serialized object seem like decent choices...

Comment: But isn't `application/json` something too generic? Following that suggestion, then any OpenOffice document should have `application/zip` MIME type as well, since they are actually zipped files.

Comment: Further improving my point: if I were to use `application/json`, then, by analogy, all SVG images should have been `application/xml` instead of `image/svg+xml`, since they are also XML documents. The same logic would apply to anything that is serialized using XML (like Google Earth KML files, that currently use `application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml` type; or Atom feeds, that use `application/atom+xml`).

Answer (score 14):

The HTML5 specification has some drag and drop examples (see the [current working draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/dnd.html#introduction-7) or the [latest version](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dnd.html#introduction-7)). In such examples, a custom MIME Type is used, and the use of site-specific MIME types is also suggested. See this snippet:

```
<p>Drop your favorite fruits below:</p>
<ol dropzone="move s:text/x-example" ondrop="dropHandler(event)">
 <-- don't forget to change the "text/x-example" type to something
 specific to your site -->
</ol>
<script>
  var internalDNDType = 'text/x-example'; // set this to something specific to your site
[...]
```

So, that's great, this means we should use a custom MIME type! (unless we are actually dragging plain text, or just a URL, or something that already has a well-known type)

But how do we create such custom MIME type?

I found no documentation about this, so I looked at other MIME types. The [list of text media types](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/index.html) had nothing special, but the [list of application media types](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/index.html) was quite interesting. Let me grab a sample from that list:

```
application/atom+xml
application/xhtml+xml
application/xmpp+xml

application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml
application/vnd.google-earth.kmz
application/vnd.iptc.g2.newsitem+xml
application/vnd.iptc.g2.packageitem+xml
application/vnd.nokia.iptv.config+xml
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.footnotes+xml
application/vnd.yamaha.openscoreformat.osfpvg+xml

application/vnd.hal+json
application/vnd.hal+xml
```

I can notice a pattern for making names:

- A dot hierarchically separates multiple "elements" (for instance, `config` is child of `iptv`, that is child of `nokia`, that is child of `vnd`).
- A hyphen separates composite words (as in `google-earth` and `openxmlformats-officedocument`).
- A plus sign serves to further specify the serializing format (`+json` and `+xml` in these examples).
- The `x-` prefix should be used for MIME types not registered with IANA (and, thus, not shown on that list).

Based on these rules, I can suggest using the following MIME type:

**application/x-mysite.myobject+json** (or *application/x-mysite.parentobject.childobject+json*)

This seems to be the most precise and correct way to specify a custom MIME type for a web application object encoded in JSON.

Comment: Shouldn't the "x-" prefix be replaced by "vnd."?

Comment: `x-` prefix is to be used for MIME types that are not registered with IANA. The `vnd.` prefix, however, is for vendor-specific MIME types that have been registered with IANA. (Good question, by the way!)

Answer (score 6):

**Update:** this Chrome bug has been fixed since version 19.

If I aim to support [Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome/) (version 12 is the latest one now), then I must stick to `text/plain`.

That's because [Chrome has improperly implemented the dataTransfer object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895923/has-chrome-improperly-implemented-the-datatransfer-object), and there is an open bug about [dataTransfer not working with non text or url](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=31037).

I've written a [simple desmontration at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cCunc/1/). It works correctly in [Mozilla Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/firefox) 3.6 and even in [Arora browser](http://arora.googlecode.com/) (version 0.10.2, WebKit version 533.3). Just for completeness, my Chrome version is 12.0.742.112 (WebKit version 534.30). The demonstration code is also available below:

```
<div id="drag" draggable="true">Drag me!</div>
<div id="drop">Drop here!</div>


#drag, #drop {
    padding: 1em 2em;
    margin: 1em 0;
}
#drag {
    background: #CFC;
}
#drop {
    background: #FCC;
}


function dragstart_handler(ev) {
    console.log('dragstart');
    ev.dataTransfer.setData('text/x-example', 'Foobar');
}

function dragover_handler(ev) {
    // Accepting whatever is dragged over here
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drop_handler(ev) {
    console.log('drop');
    console.log(ev.dataTransfer.types);

    if (ev.dataTransfer.types) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < ev.dataTransfer.types.length; i++) {
            var type = ev.dataTransfer.types[i];
            console.log(type, ev.dataTransfer.getData(type));
        }
    }

    console.log(ev.dataTransfer.getData('text/x-example'));
}

var drag = document.getElementById('drag');
drag.addEventListener('dragstart', dragstart_handler, false);

var drop = document.getElementById('drop');
drop.addEventListener('dragover', dragover_handler, false);
drop.addEventListener('drop', drop_handler, false);
```

Comment: The Chrome bug was fixed as of version 19.

Comment: And was broken again by version 22 (possibly earlier)

Comment: @rtcarlson Running Google Chrome 29.0.1547.62 on Linux. The demonstration linked in my answer works correctly here, so I don't think this bug still exists nowadays. (BTW, Chrome 22 is quite old…)

Comment: It seems broken in IE11 =(

Answer (score 0):

Use 'application/json' as a wrapper for any other metadata that you may like, including mime-type of linked files, or the html you want to use in the browser.

```
{ 'assets': [
      {
       'color': 'foo',
       'text': 'bar',
       'uri': 'http://', // location of asset
       'type': 'application/zip', // mime-type of asset
       'html': '<div>html representation</div>'
       // .. more properties
      }
   // ...more assets
   ]
}
```

Comment: Plain `application/json` doesn't feel right. Maybe something along the lines `application/x-myapp.myobj+json` ?