# <script type="text/javascript+protovis"> what does + sign mean?

Tags: javascript, protovis

As the title asks,

What does the `+` sign mean in `<script type="text/javascript+protovis">`?

Are there any good materials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shamelessly stolen from a different answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6877405/759019).

Pattern for naming mimetypes is as follows:

> A dot hierarchically separates multiple "elements" (for instance,
> config is child of iptv, that is child of nokia, that is child of
> vnd).
>
> A hyphen separates composite words (as in google-earth and
> openxmlformats-officedocument).
>
> A **plus sign** serves to further specify
> the serializing format (+json and +xml in these examples).
>
> The x- prefix should be used for MIME types not registered with IANA (and,
> thus, not shown on that list).

Also, `text/javascript+protovis` is not equivalent to `text/javascript`. The two **could** be parsed differently.

Comment: Forgive me that I'm absolute newbie.
> A plus sign serves to further specify the serializing format (+json and +xml in these examples).
What does serializing format mean?

Comment: You could read about what serialization is on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization)